# Remove array from multidimensional array if key contains

Tags: php, arrays

I have following Multidimensional Array:

```
Array
(
    [2014-01-21|699] => Array
        (
            [id] => 331
            [datum] => 2014-01-21
            [title] => workshop 1
            [alias] => workshop news
        )

    [1970-01-01|507] => Array
        (
            [id] => 331
            [datum] => 1970-01-01
            [title] => workshop 2
            [alias] => workshop news
        )

 [1970-01-01|780] => Array
        (
            [id] => 331
            [datum] => 1970-01-01
            [title] => workshop 3
            [alias] => workshop news   
        )
)
```

How can I remove every Array which key contains 1970-01-01 that the Multidimensional array looks like this:

```
  Array
    (
        [2014-01-21|699] => Array
            (
                [id] => 331
                [datum] => 2014-01-21
                [title] => workshop 1
                [alias] => workshop news
            )
)
```

Thanks!

Toni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a brute-force approach of a `foreach` loop and [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

```
foreach ($yourArray as $key => $data) {
    if ($data['datum'] == '1970-01-01') {
        unset($yourArray[$key]);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to have a re-usable callback that can perform the necessary check for you:

```
function checkDate($record) {
    return ($record['datum'] != '1970-01-01');
}

$filteredArray = array_filter($yourArray, 'checkDate');
```